# My question was wrongly "put on hold" as "off-topic"

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-hold

My [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1459560)  is truly clear-cut: Do devices that implement certain machine code instructions (which are an extension to the ARMv8 ISA) exist? (I give instructions for how to check it.)

As [per the topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), this is a question about "computer hardware".

It was closed with the explanation that "**Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.**". This is absurd because I am *not* asking for any kind of recommendation, and any answers would *not ever become outdated*. Furthermore the explanation says that I should "**describe [my] situation and the specific problem [I am] trying to solve**" which is just patronizing, the problem I am trying to solve is find out if support for these instructions exists in real hardware.

Comment: Product "recommendation" questions don't necessarily need to ask for a recommendation. Questions of the form "what products have these features", or "are there products with these features", are "identify products for me" questions. Whether or not responses will endorse specific products isn't really the issue. The problems are that questions asking for a list aren't a good fit for a Q&A site, and product information is short-lived, so answers don't have long-term value. The wording of the standard closure reasons is very generic, which can be confusing if it doesn't perfectly fit a question.

Comment: The question in your question is: "Is there any hardware that actually implements the SHA3 (Keccak) instructions?".   That wording asks to identify products with a certain feature.

Answer (score 7):

Its pretty broad. We don't do yes/no answers, we do answers in detail, and literally the only way to answer your question is with a hardware recommendation.

So literally the only way to answer your question is to take an arm machine, check processor flags, and post what the machine is. And you would end up with more than one answer, which dosen't work for us.